# failed to resolve: use of undeclared type `MaximumBlockWeight`

Tags: substrate

I am following the tutorial https://substrate.dev/docs/en/tutorials/upgrade-a-chain/sudo-upgrade

However, when I try to build the release, it's giving me the following errors.  Does anyone know what might be causing the problem?

```
     Compiling node-template-runtime v3.0.0 (/home/bill/substrate-node-template/runtime)
  error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared type `MaximumBlockWeight`
     --> /home/bill/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:302:70
      |
  302 |     pub MaximumSchedulerWeight: Weight = Perbill::from_percent(80) * MaximumBlockWeight::get();
      |                                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ use of undeclared type `MaximumBlockWeight`

  error[E0308]: mismatched types
     --> /home/bill/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:302:42
      |
  302 |     pub MaximumSchedulerWeight: Weight = Perbill::from_percent(80) * MaximumBlockWeight::get();
      |                                 ------   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `u64`, found struct `Perbill`
      |                                 |
      |                                 expected `u64` because of return type

  error[E0277]: the trait bound `Perbill: num_traits::sign::Unsigned` is not satisfied
     --> /home/bill/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:302:68
      |
  302 |     pub MaximumSchedulerWeight: Weight = Perbill::from_percent(80) * MaximumBlockWeight::get();
      |                                                                    ^ the trait `num_traits::sign::Unsigned` is not implemented for `Perbill`
      |
      = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Mul` for `Perbill`

  error[E0277]: the trait bound `Perbill: From<u32>` is not satisfied
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply this change to your code.

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/commit/332399d16668a6c769f1a7db154bb9ea3b50e61c

There're a lot of updates every day, please keep watching the upstream if you want to make a runtime upgrade.

Here's the latest node-template https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/bin/node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs

Comment: Thanks!  Do you know if there is a substrate-front-end-template that will work with this version?

Comment: I assume that the v3.0.0 one would work, if you experience errors they may just need a types specified. Here is more info on how to do that https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/FAQ/#the-node-returns-a-could-not-convert-error-on-send and https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/start/types.extend